# How to assign a long variable in a Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an object as a variable ,so I want to assign this object as an Id my link. 
I wrote the below code but it does not work.

here is my code :

```js
$(".rooms").each(function(index, element) {
  var policy = $(".policy").val();
  alert(policy)
 $('.search-box2').load('page.html?id=+policy+&debug=true');


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rooms">
<input type="text" value="{ &quot;id&quot; : { &quot;provider&quot; : { &quot;provider_id&quot; : &quot;10&quot;, &quot;dmnid&quot; : 2452 }, &quot;NonRefundable&quot; : &quot;false&quot;, &quot;id&quot; : &quot;#1#c2ce302a2032435c96a0b80b8dadc5b2@63a517cd8bca4b318ae398e329509f68&quot; } }" class="policy">
</div>
```

Comment: worked for me..

Comment: Convert the object into string before passing it into the URL.

Comment: `policy` is a string. To use it's value, concat it as `'page.html?id=' + policy + '&debug=true'`.

Comment: @Tushar it does not work for me and it shows undefined instead of an Id in my link

Comment: @RohitJindal How can I convert it into string ? I have been trying but it shows undefined instead of an Id

Comment: @inaz by using JSON.stringify(policy);

Comment: @RohitJindal i used that but in link I have this page.html?id="{  and I i don't have the full variable

Comment: @inaz As Tushar suggested, pass the policy in that way . It will work

Comment: @RohitJindal i passed but still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)** like this:

```
var obj ='{ &quot;id&quot; : { &quot;provider&quot; : { &quot;provider_id&quot; : &quot;10&quot;, &quot;dmnid&quot; : 2452 }, &quot;NonRefundable&quot; : &quot;false&quot;, &quot;id&quot; : &quot;#1#c2ce302a2032435c96a0b80b8dadc5b2@63a517cd8bca4b318ae398e329509f68&quot; } }',
    b = new Blob([obj], {type: "application/json"}),
    url = URL.createObjectURL(b);
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/fuqhrmdn/)

Comment: why u are using backup.json file ?

Comment: @inaz it's  just a example.

Comment: My code still does not work  I want to pass the id to a page but my id is not compelete

Comment: @inaz What is `id`?